# react.js does not update DOM after having changed state array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to implement a game in react where I have the board as an two dimensional array in the initial state of the parent class. Tiles are rendered by iterating through that array. I pass those children a function as a prop so that they can change that state array.

Now, when I use that function to change the array, the HTML does not update. The array gets updated when I call setState but it never rerenders. I tried this.forceUpdate() but still no luck. What I then did was to pass a function from that child to the parent through the function to update that child's state and this works, but I need the function from the parent to call itself recursively to update the board. I feel like I might have hit an anti-pattern. How could I change my code in order for the DOM to update, please?

There is parts missing but those are all the components involved. statusBoard is the internal version of the board featuring the solution. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are linking props and state together you have to create a componentWillReceiveProps function like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      positionX: nextProps.columnPosition,
      positionY: nextProps.rowPosition
    });
  }
```

When games state changes and passes it down as props to Field, fields own internal state doesn't get updated at that point because it is relying on its own state. this is an anti pattern and you should avoid Field having to have any state and just rely on its props it gets passed and have a parent component that is handling the state of everything.

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have edited this in but this still does not work. I have read about the componentWillReceiveProps and understand its purpose.

Comment: This totally makes sense, but I don't see how I could only have this handled by the field? I have to save the field somewhere central to iterate over it, right? Could you push me in the right direction for how to change my component structure in order to have something like I described above?

Comment: Is there anyway you can get a fully working code pen or jsbin for this? it would be easier to see the full code/actual example

Comment: Of course, here you go: http://codepen.io/SebastianJvF/pen/BLqBvQ . Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that you can see what I want to achieve by uncommenting the changeExternal lines in the Minesweeper component.

Comment: http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/rrqBgv i added a missing piece to the componentwillreceive props:  `componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
            this.setState({ 
                external: nextProps.columnInformation,
                positionX: nextProps.columnPosition,
                positionY: nextProps.rowPosition });
    }`

Comment: Ah, I had overseen that as well. Thank you very much for your help!